# Why are superfluous permissions showing up in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, permissions, appcelerator, android-permissions

In Appcelerator Titanium, I've build a simple one-page app that adds Roman Numerals. As best as I can tell, it has no need to ask for any permissions.

However, my friend testing the app told me it asks for access to the network and in the build/android/ directory the AndroidManifest.xml file includes these lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

There's nothing in the tiapp.xml file requesting these permissions and I started with a stock, blank project and don't import any modules or widgets.

Where did these permission requests originate? How do I get rid of them?

All the info I can find discusses how to add or request a permission, but nothing explains how to ensure unnecessary permissions don't show up in the generated AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite possible that those permissions are defined in one of the Android Libraries used by your app. Android build system provides tools to control how manifest merge is done. Try disabling manifest merge for `<uses-permission/>` elements of your app's manifest. See [Merge Multiple Manifest Files](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html) docs.

Comment: you will still have them without any module because they are added by the builder.py script as mentioned in my answer above. But you can edit this file to remove them and check if the app still compiles

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the builder.py (.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/5.3.0.GA/android/builder.py) somewhere around line 982. There you'll find the default permissions for Android. You can try to remove them and see if you have any errors. Make sure to disable the analytics first!